# Decode mJPEG to a format usable by libx264

Tags: c++, video, decoding, x264, libx264

I am compressing frames coming from webcam with libx264. So far I used YUY2 raw frames and swscale to transcode the frames to I420, which is usable by x264.

Anyway I would like to add support for mJPEG webcams (usually webcam provides both, but mJPEG allows higher frame rates and resolutions). What can I use to transcode mJPEG to some format, that can be used by x264?

Answer (score 1):

If you already use swscale why not to use ffmpeg/libav (libavcodec) for decoding mjpeg?

Comment: please take a look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443322/decoding-mjpeg-with-libavcodec