# Decoding mJPEG with libavcodec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding, libavcodec

I am creating video conference application. I have discovered that webcams (at least 3 I have) provide higher resolutions and framerates for mJPEG output format. So far I was using YUY2, converted in I420 for compression with X264. To transcode mJPEG to I420, I need to decode it first. I am trying to decode images from webcam with libavcodec. This is my code.

Initialization:

```
// mJPEG to I420 conversion
AVCodecContext * _transcoder = nullptr;
AVFrame * _outputFrame;
AVPacket _inputPacket;

avcodec_register_all();
_outputFrame = av_frame_alloc();
av_frame_unref(_outputFrame);
av_init_packet(&_inputPacket);

AVCodec * codecDecode = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG);

_transcoder = avcodec_alloc_context3(codecDecode);
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(_transcoder, codecDecode);
_transcoder->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_FAST;
_transcoder->pix_fmt = AVPixelFormat::AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
_transcoder->width = width;
_transcoder->height = height;
avcodec_open2(_transcoder, codecDecode, nullptr);
```

Decoding:

```
_inputPacket.size = size;
_inputPacket.data = data;

int got_picture;
int decompressed_size = avcodec_decode_video2(_transcoder, _outputFrame, &got_picture, &_inputPacket);
```

But so far, what I am getting is a green screen. Where am I wrong?

UPD:
I have enabled libavcodec logging, but there are not warnings or errors.
Also I have discovered that _outputframe has AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P as format and colorspace, which does not fit any on values in libavcodec's enums (the actual value is 156448160).

Comment: 1) This are too small snippets of code to say for sure. 2) You can't really hardcode decoding to yuv420p (same for width/height) because decoding format depends from source stream and will be overwritten by decoder. So make sure you use correct colorspace when you looking at result of decoding. 3) Have you enabled ffmpeg/libav logging (av_log_set_callback) too look if they output any errors?

Comment: @nobody555, thanks for the insights. I have updated the answer with new information. Please let me know which code do you need to better understand the problem. Regarding 2) - so, if I need I420 as output how should I set it up? Is it possible to obtain I420 from mJPEG with libavcodec, or I should look for other solutions?

Comment: if you need I420 than you decoded mjpeg for what ever libavcodec decided (depends from you source) and than use swscale to convert it to I420.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped, though the decompression take a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suggestions from comments, I came up with working solution.

Initialization:

```
av_init_packet(&_inputPacket);

AVCodec * codecDecode = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG);

_transcoder = avcodec_alloc_context3(codecDecode);
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(_transcoder, codecDecode);
avcodec_open2(_transcoder, codecDecode, nullptr);

// swscale contex init
mJPEGconvertCtx = sws_getContext(width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P, 
        width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

// x264 pic init
x264_picture_t _pic_in;
x264_picture_alloc(&_pic_in, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);
_pic_in.img.i_csp = X264_CSP_I420 ;
_pic_in.img.i_plane = 3;
_pic_in.img.i_stride[0] = width;
_pic_in.img.i_stride[1] = width / 2;
_pic_in.img.i_stride[2] = width / 2;

_pic_in.i_type = X264_TYPE_AUTO ;
_pic_in.i_qpplus1 = 0;
```

Transcoding:

```
_inputPacket.size = size;
_inputPacket.data = data;

int got_picture;

// decode
avcodec_decode_video2(_transcoder, _outputFrame, &got_picture, &_inputPacket); 

// transform
sws_scale(_mJPEGconvertCtx, _outputFrame->data, _outputFrame->linesize, 0, height, 
        _pic_in.img.plane, _pic_in.img.i_stride);
```

Afterwards, _pic_in is used directly by x264. Image is fine, but the transcoding times are horrible for higher resolutions.